# Critical points in functions $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I have a problem on critical points of a function, where the function is: $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+kxy$$ where $k \in\mathbb{R}$.

- The problem says to find and classify the critical points of the function. Noting the answer will depend on whether $k$ is positive, negative or $0$.
- So far, i have differentiated respected to $x$ and $y$ giving:
  $$\frac{\delta}{\delta x}=2x+ky$$
  $$\frac{\delta}{\delta y}=2y+kx$$
- I then set $\frac{\delta}{\delta x}=0$, to find what $x$ equalled and got $x=\frac{-ky}{2}$.
  Then i set $\frac{\delta}{\delta y}=0$ and set $x=\frac{-ky}{2}$, to find my $y$ value, which gave me $y\left(4-k^{2}\right)=0$.
- This showed that $k=\pm2.$ Which substituting into my $x$ value, gave me $x=0$.
- So in conclusion I guessed that I found my critical point to be $(0,0)$, when $k=\pm2$.

---

Is this in anyway along the right lines, and I know I'm meant to be doing more for this problem, as the problem is stating "find and classify the critical points"  where as i have only found 1 critical point.

Any help on this would be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: $(0,0)$ is _always_ a critical point, regardless of the value of $k$. This can easily be checked directly from the partial derivatives (before you do any solving).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system of equations yields $$y(4-k^2)=0.$$ Thus, it follows that $y=0$ or $k=\pm 2.$ The former case gives the origin, so considering when $k=\pm 2$ in the system gives, in the $+2$ case, the solution $x=-y,$ and in the $-2$ case, $x=y.$ The origin satisfies both, so that the complete solution set (infinite) is all $(x,y)$ satisfying the relation $x=\pm y.$

Comment: So does this mean, that the critical points of the function are $(0,0)$ and $(x, -y)$ and $(x, y)$ ?

Comment: Or am I meant to now find out what the x and -y, and x and y values are?

Comment: @TheStatistician You can't find them out one by one -- they're uncountable. They are the points on the pair of lines $x=\pm y.$ In coordinate form, if you want, $(x,x),(x,-x),$ with $x$ arbitrary.